# Group plot: Replacing the values (labels) on x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, groupplots

I'd like to replace numerical labels (e.g., 1,2,3,4,5) on x-axis with names (e.g., `A,B,C,D,E`) in a group plot environment on a **case-by-case** basis.  The group plot environment seems to easily support only a **common** x-axis across all group plots.  How can I change the x-axis labels on the first plot to {`A,B,C,D,E`}, and {`F,G,H,I,S`} on the second plot?

I've purposefully titled my question to resemble the following post: [TikZ: Replacing the values (labels) on x-axis with names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186949/tikz-replacing-the-values-labels-on-x-axis-with-names)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
A   B      
1   3
2   4
3   1
4   7
5   8
  \end{filecontents*}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mydata2.dat}
C   D      
1   7
2   5
3   4
4   6
5   7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=2 by 1, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis},
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 1}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};
\addplot[black, mark=x, only marks]
    table[x=C,y=D]{mydata2.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 2}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=C,y=D]{mydata2.dat};
         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to learn how to create customized x-axis options (customized for each individual plot in group plot environment) instead of relying on common x-axis labels across the spectrum of plots in group plot.

Comment: You can use `yticklabels={A,B,C,D,E}` and so in the option of `\nextgroupplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
        xtick={1,...,5},
        xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E}
```

in the options of `\nextgroupplot`. Change `xtick={1...,5},` as you wish. Further don't use `\it{...}` as `\it` is tex command and it doesn't take an argument. Use `\itshape` as I did.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
A   B
1   3
2   4
3   1
4   7
5   8
  \end{filecontents*}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mydata2.dat}
C   D
1   7
2   5
3   4
4   6
5   7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=2 by 1, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis},
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\itshape Title 1},
            xtick={1,...,5},
            xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};
\addplot[black, mark=x, only marks]
    table[x=C,y=D]{mydata2.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\itshape Title 2},
        xtick={1,...,5},
            xticklabels={F,G,H,I,S}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=C,y=D]{mydata2.dat};
         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Generally `\nextgroupplot` takes all options that are taken by `axis` environment. Hence you can customize all your `x axis` parameters here case by case.

Comment: @warship Happy to help. :-)